# Android app communication with php files written in code igniter framework

Tags: php, android, mysql, codeigniter, webserver

I am developing an android app. We also have a website developed using PHP/MYSQL and hosted on a server. I want my app to communicate with the server to access the MYSQL database. PHP files are written in codeIgniter Framework. Where can I get the webservices to invoke from my app ?
I don't understand how to make my app and the server communicate. Pls help me.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way in my opinion is to use JSON, take look at this simple example: http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/connecting-mysql-database

Comment: The link you have suggested works right if the files are written in core PHP whereas in codeIgniter framework, we cannot access in such a way, they have some built-in mechanism which doesn't expose links like http://example.com/helloworld.php

Answer (score 1):

It's really easy :

1. You can create a Controller (let's call it "Webservices").
2. In this controller write a method that do excatly what you want and output the data (in JSON format for example)
3. Then call the URL (http://www.mywebsite/webservices/method) from your Android app, you'll get the data JSON encoded.
4. Finally parse the data in your Android app.